# SQL grouping by month with different events

Tags: sql, count, grouping

I have the following data:

```
  Month      Event
 ------------------
  2010-12    0
  2010-12    0      
  2010-12    1
  2011-01    0
  2011-01    1      
  2011-01    1 
  2011-01    2
```

And I want to count how many of each event happened each month:

```
 Month    Event  Counter
 ------------------------
 2010-12   0      2
 2010-12   1      1
 2010-12   2      0
 2011-01   0      1
 2011-01   1      2
 2011-01   2      1
```

I guess it could be done by grouping like

```
SELECT 
    SUM(event), MONTH(month), YEAR(month)
FROM 
    data
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(month), YEAR(year)
```

but it doesn't work for some reason. Or should I create new variable, counter, and attach it to data?

**Update:** `SELECT` and `COUNT` works, but it doesn't give 0 counts for absent events. So output is

```
 Month    Event  Counter
 ------------------------
 2010-12   0      2
 2010-12   1      1
 2011-01   0      1
 2011-01   1      2
 2011-01   2      1
```

without the line

```
2010-12  2   0
```

which shows that there were 0 events of type 2.

Comment: try this: SELECT SUM(event), MONTH(month), YEAR(month)
FROM data
GROUP BY month

Comment: Do you want to split the data in your Month column for group by?

Comment: Maybe there is also an Events table? Because in the your desired output appears the event 2 of  2010-12, which isn't included in the sample data.

Comment: SELECT and COUNT works, but it doesn't give zero for absent events. In 2010-12 there is no any 2 type event, and in ideal it should return 0 as counter for 2 type event for 2010-12

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you -

```
SELECT Month, Event, SUM(Event) as Counter
FROM data
GROUP BY Month, Event
```

There is no Year column here for year to be placed in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show month and year also separately, you can use

```
SELECT LEFT(MONTH,4) Year, RIGHT(MONTH,2) Month, 
Event , Count(Event) Counter 
FROM Data 
GROUP BY LEFT(MONTH,4), RIGHT(MONTH,2), Event
```

Otherwise, for simple event count with available data, this will work.

```
SELECT Month, Event , Count(Event) Counter 
FROM Data 
GROUP BY Month, Event
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a COUNT, not a sum:

```
SELECT month, event, COUNT(*)
FROM data
GROUP BY month, event
```

You want to COUNT the instances of your group: that is, count that number of times this month and event type show up together.